# how to set simulink matlab function block memory to dynamic in 2016

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink, motion-detection

I am using the bwboundaries function which is unbounded and Simulink is spewing out errors that it needs to be bounded.

how do I set this to dynamic memory allocation for Matlab function block in Matlab version R2016a.

I did try the configuration parameters>all parameters>use dynamic memory for the model but it does not work. Also used ert.rlc but is not working and changing the memory constraints under code generation was all too volatile and did not work

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation support for MATLAB Function block was introduced in R2017a.

Comment: Is the output of your MATLAB Function block dynamically sized, or just some of the intermediate calculations that use bwboundaries?  If the latter, then I would suggest to put all of your code into another (function) file, and have that file called from the MATLAB Function block (as an extrinsic function).  That will get around the dynamic memory issue.